# How can I replace .gif with .jpg while a "dragging" function is active?

Tags: jquery, ipad, safari, gif, lag

I am getting my senior project gallery-ready for a show this weekend.

It is optimized for iPad. You should be able to drag around the frames & gifs with your mouse.
In the case of iPad, they're draggable by touch too.

However, something irritating is happening.

When I export the webpage onto my homescreen, it turns into a "native" app. Even though the dragging function works perfectly in Safari on iPad, and on the computer, in this "app" format, the dragging is laggy.

The changing frames in the gifs cannot keep up with the dragging for some reason, and it makes the movement very laggy 50% of the time. Sometimes it works perfectly, sometimes it is painfully slow.

So. I was hoping there was some jquery script out there that would allow me to switch out the .gif images with .jpgs while the draggable() script is taking place.

Any ideas? I am good at following directions but may need to be

Comment: The title has a typo! .jpg not .jps :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jquery to switch out the attr of the image. I'm not sure what the draggable function looks like but it should have some kind of active state that you can put the switch in, and have it switch back when it's inactive. http://api.jquery.com/attr/

$('#greatphoto').attr('src', 'yourphoto.jpg');